# Simplified and efficient way of passing props and conditions

Tags: reactjs

Here in this code I am trying to change the text of the button whenever I hover on it but the issue is I have to write a lot of code which is not much efficient.

```
<div className="Launcher_Actions_visible Launcher_buttons_primary" 
     onMouseEnter={this.onMouseoverRemove}
     onMouseLeave={this.onMouseoutRemove}>
       {this.state.removeHover ? "Remove" : "Task name"}
</div>
<div className="Launcher_Actions_visible Launcher_buttons_primary"
     onMouseEnter={this.onMouseoverRemove}
     onMouseLeave={this.onMouseoutRemove}>
       {this.state.removeHover ? "Remove" : "New TeamSync"}
</div>
```

Similarly, I have some few more buttons to add on these props and condition. And moreover before the string "Remove", I want to add a icon. So I am a bit confused how to do the same. Looking for a simplified way of writing the same.

[image: This is the expected result]
**The issue that Raised after successfully implementing the task is:**

If the initial text size is bigger then the hover state it starts flickering as the state keeps on changing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-swirles-wzsmj

You will easily understand seeing the code.

I am bit confused how to use ref to get the initial width and set it for the hover state too and moreover it will be great if someone can get me a solution that let me keep the button size as per the text size and without flickering(changing the state).

Comment: Can you create a sreenshot of result that you expect?

Comment: Are you using a div to act as a button?

Comment: @RyanNghiem I added the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to handle such situations via `CSS` in which case you would be able to add transitions to hovered and removed text

```
<div className="Launcher_Actions_visible Launcher_buttons_primary">
    <span className="normalText">Remove</span>
    <span className="hoverText">Task name</span>
</div>
<div className="Launcher_Actions_visible Launcher_buttons_primary">
    <span className="normalText">Remove</span>
    <span className="hoverText">New TeamSync</span>
</div>
```

and scss would be

```
.Launcher_Actions_visible.Launcher_buttons_primary {
    .normalText {
       display: block;
    }
    .hoverText {
       display: none;
    }
    &:hover {
       .normalText {
          display: none;
       }
       .hoverText {
          display: block;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you shubham, with CSS this works but I want to get it done using react so finding a way.

Comment: @Sohan, using React or Javascript is not always a best solution for things that can be done using CSS

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work?

```
state = {
   mouseEnter: false
}

onMousenterHover() {
    /* if mouseEnter is false then set to true */
    return !this.state.mouseEnter ? this.setState({mouseEnter: true}) : null
}

onMouseleaveHover() {
    /* if mouseEnter is true then set to false */
    return this.state.mouseEnter === true ? this.setState({mouseEnter: false}) : null
}

return <div>
    <div className="Launcher_Actions_visible Launcher_buttons_primary"
        onMouseEnter={() => this.onMousenterHover()}
        onMouseLeave={() => this.onMouseleaveHover()}>
        {this.state.mouseEnter ? "Remove" : "New TeamSync"}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnak you Famil. This is similar to what I wrote already and is not much efficient.